# Sorting Data in Tables

Tags: data

Am I allowed to sort data in tables?

Say in my notebook, I recorded the following:

```
Distance (cm)    Time (s)
± 0.01 cm        ± 0.02 s

100.00           10.00
  0.00            0.00
 10.00            1.00
 50.00            5.00
 25.00            2.50
```

Can I sort the data (for a formal report) into the following?

```
Distance (cm)    Time (s)
± 0.01 cm        ± 0.02 s

  0.00            0.00
 10.00            1.00
 25.00            2.50
 50.00            5.00
100.00           10.00
```

I haven't modified the data, but only the order in which they were taken, therefore, I think I am allowed.

Comment: I would say this would be within the bounds of complete honesty. Especially if in the methods section you mention the order used to observe the data.

Comment: Who could possibly grant or deny permission to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on whether the result in any given trial depends on the previous sequence of trials.  For example, is this a state machine for which the output and next state is a combination of the present inputs + the current state or is it purely combinatorial, where the output is always dependent only on the input?

If each trial is independent, there's no harm in sorting it any way you like, especially if it clarifies the relationship between input and output.  But if there's a sequential relationship, no, you cannot sort the data.